# Java LinkedTree Help

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a linked tree but I am getting a nullpointer exception when I run it. Can you help me fix it up.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at assign2Trees.LinkedTree.size(LinkedTree.java:16)
        at assign2Trees.LinkedTree.main(LinkedTree.java:80)
```

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedTree<E> implements Tree<E>{

    private Node<E> root;

    public LinkedTree()
    {
        super();
    }
    public int size()
    {
        return root.getChildren().size() + 1;
    }   
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        if(root == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public Iterator<E> iterator() 
    {
        return new Iterator<E>()
        {
            private int i = 0;

            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return i < LinkedTree.this.size();
            }
            public E next() throws NoSuchElementException
            {
               if (!hasNext()) 
               {
                   return null;
               }
               return (E) LinkedTree.this.root.getChildren().get(i++);
            }
            public void remove() 
            {

            }
        };
    }
    public E replace(E oldE, E newE) 
    {
        int i = root.getChildren().indexOf(oldE);
        root.getChildren().add(i, (Node<E>) newE);  
        return newE;
    }
    public E root() throws EmptyTreeException 
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyTreeException ();
        return this.root();
    }
    public E parent(E node) 
    {
        return (E) ((Node<E>) root.getChildren()).getParent((root.getChildren().get(root.getChildren().indexOf(node))));    
    }
    public Iterable<E> children(E node) 
    {
        return (Iterable<E>) root.getChildren().listIterator();
    }
    public void delete(E node) throws RootNonDeletableException 
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new RootNonDeletableException();
        else
            root.getChildren().remove(root.getChildren().indexOf(node));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedTree<Node<String>> tree = new LinkedTree<Node<String>>();
        System.out.println(tree.size());

    }


}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node<E>{

    protected E contents;
    protected List<Node<E>> children;
    protected Node<E> parent;

    public Node()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Node(E contents)
    {
        this.setContents(contents);
    }
    public List<Node<E>> getChildren()
    {
        if(this.children == null)
        {
            return new ArrayList<Node<E>>();
        }
        return this.children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Node<E>> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }
    public void addChild(Node<E> child)
    {
        if (children == null)
        {
            children = new ArrayList<Node<E>>();
        }
        children.add(child);
    }
    public E getContents()
    {
        return this.contents;
    }
    public void setContents(E contents)
    {
        this.contents = contents;
    }
    public Node<E> getParent(Node<E> node)
    {
        return node.parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Node<E> parent, Node<E> child)
    {
        child.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't remove the text from your questions once they've been fixed. Others might experience a similar issue and find help here as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` is null. You're not intializing `root` to anything or checking that it's not null before accessing it on this line:

```
return root.getChildren().size() + 1;
```

Perhaps:

```
return (root == null) ? 0 : root.getChildren().size()+1;
```

So more than likely what you really ought to do is set `root` to a brand new node in your constructor, say:

```
public LinkedTree()
{
    super();
    root = new Node<E>();
}
```

You also have an error with your `root()` function:

```
public E root() throws Exception 
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new Exception ();
    return this.root();
}
```

Will call itself.  Perhaps you meant

```
public E root() throws Exception 
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new Exception ();
    return this.root;
}
```

Now to start building your tree in your main method you can do something like:

```
tree.root().addChild(new Node<String>("test"));
```

What this does is get the root of the tree, then adds a child to it.

Supposing you want to add a complicated structure, say, a node with a child, you could do:

```
Node<String> deepest = new Node<String>("deepest node");
Node<String> deeper  = new Node<String>("deeper node");
deeper.addChild(deepest);
tree.root().addChild(deeper);
```

This gives you a tree with structure:

```
[root] +- [deeper] +- deepest
```

Comment: @Brian: then the correct etiquette, now, is to accept this as the correct answer or indicate why the observed behavior is still undesired.

Comment: I also don't know how to start building the tree in my main method.

Comment: ok Mark so would you say my code implements a LinkTree, like it works?

Comment: @Brian: depends on your definition of "works", I'd recommend unit testing to be sure.

Comment: what I mean is do the methods all look ok or do you see an major errors in the code.

Comment: also when I run the main method you suggested I get a stackOverFlowError : 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError  
 at assign2Trees.LinkedTree.isEmpty(LinkedTree.java:24)  
 at assign2Trees.LinkedTree.root(LinkedTree.java:61)    
 at assign2Trees.LinkedTree.root(LinkedTree.java:63)

Comment: @Brian: With latest modifications your `isEmpty` function will fail and your `parent` function looks suspect. Among other things, I wouldn't have expected you to need a `Node` class in order to implement this, and if this is homework, you could get docked for that.  Ultimately you need to **unit test** your code to be sure it performs the desired function.

Comment: Well its a linkTree of Nodes right so a node for the root with a list of children each with a node parent and sibling node and a list of children for them. So the node class allows me to have a list of child nodes. Also the parent method I have it finding the index of the object and gets whatever is stored at that index then gets the parent of the node. I had to cast to Node<E> because the interface we are implementing is type E not Node<E>

Comment: @Brian: each node can just be considered a Tree.  So the tree has a root *value* rather than a root *node*.  Then each `Tree` has a list of children, which are also `Tree`s.  Thus, when you ask for a parent, you'd hand the parent `Tree`, rather than the parent `Node`...and so, no `Node` class required.

Comment: Actually I have a question, if I do: implements Tree<Node<E>> instead of Tree<E> will that allow me to not have to cast from E to Node. Would that be a better way to go?

Comment: @Brian, the best way to go is to dump the `Node<E>` class entirely, it's not needed, and it's just complicating your code.

Comment: @Brian: I think you should start by considering your interface.  Of all the questions you've posted to fix errors in your code, you're missing the fundamental problem: you don't quite understand how to construct this thing.  Perhaps (and I can't believe I'm recommending this) you should post a new question asking for conceptual help; please spend some time writing up you're understanding *before* you ask that question, though.

Comment: well I know it needs to be a LinkedTree so using nodes I believe and one node for the root with a list of nodes for its children for which each node has a parent node and a child node.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public List<Node<E>> getChildren()
{
    if(this.children == null)
    {
        return new ArrayList<Node<E>>();
    }
    return this.children;
}
```

to

```
public List<Node<E>> getChildren()
{
    if(this.children == null)
    {
        return this.children = new ArrayList<Node<E>>(); // set the this.children field and return.
    }
    return this.children;
}
```

Tell me how that goes.

Comment: er, or even better, remove that return statement and just have the one at the end.  same behavior, easier to read. btw: this isn't the error.

Comment: yes I know but error is easier to say in a way. Can you help me write my main method just how do I start building the tree?

Answer (score 0):

The root node is never initialized, so you're trying to call getChildren() on an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok so do I do that in my Main method or in the constructor? Actually what would a main method look like for this class, I am confused.